# Rearranging containers for mobile devices

Tags: css, html, mobile, containers

I'd like to make my desktop-friendly site mobile-friendly aswell.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtC8n.png) is how it looks for mobile devices.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmJ4b.png) is how I want it to look for mobile users.

The reasoning behind this layout is that it looks good on a desktop, where there are 2 columns per row.

Html code:

```
<html>
 <div class="outer-container">
  <div class="inner-container">text</div>
  <div class="inner-container">img</div>
 </div>
 <div class="outer-container">
  <div class="inner-container">img</div>
  <div class="inner-container">text</div>
 </div>
 <div class="outer-container">
  <div class="inner-container">text</div>
  <div class="inner-container">img</div>
 </div>
</html>
```

Css code:

```
.outer-container{
  width:100%;
}

.inner-container{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px){
  .inner-container{
  width:100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flex` to do this. Create a `column` and use the `order` attribute on the children to re-organize as you see fit.

```css
.outer-container{
  width:100%;

}

.inner-container{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px){
  .inner-container{
  width:100%;
  }
  .outer-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .t {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
 <div class="outer-container">
  <div class="inner-container t">text</div>
  <div class="inner-container i">img</div>
 </div>
 <div class="outer-container">
  <div class="inner-container i">img</div>
  <div class="inner-container t">text</div>
 </div>
 <div class="outer-container">
  <div class="inner-container t">text</div>
  <div class="inner-container i">img</div>
 </div>
</html>
```